# Constant injection error in module config in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

Problem is I can't insert constant from one module to another's module config.

myApp.module.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', [
    'myApp.base',
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'myApp.common'
]);
```

myApp.config.js

```
'use strict';

angular
    .module('myApp')
    .constant('appConfig', applicationConfiguration())

function applicationConfiguration() {
    var config = {
        debug: true
    };

    switch (window.location.hostname) {
        case 'www.myapp.net':
            config.apiUrl = 'www.myapp.net/';
            config.publicSiteUrl = "www.myapp-public.net";
            break;
        case 'localhost':
            config.apiUrl = 'http://localhost:61057/';
            config.publicSiteUrl = "http://localhost:57563/";
            break;
    }

    return config;
}
```

This is where I am trying to use it:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.base', [
    'myApp'
])
    .config(['$stateProvider','appConfig', function configState($stateProvider, appConfig) {

        $stateProvider
            .state('public', {
                ...
            })
            .state('publicSite', {
                url: appConfig.publicSiteUrl,
                external: true
            });
    }])
    .run(function(){});
```

When I run the code, I keep on getting following error:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp.base due to:
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: appConfig
```

Comment: Change `.config(['appConfig', function configState($stateProvider, appConfig) {` to `.config(['$stateProvider', 'appConfig', function configState($stateProvider, appConfig) {`

Comment: @Tushar it didn't work with that too. I already tried that.

Comment: Change `.constant('appConfig', applicationConfiguration())` to `.constant('appConfig', applicationConfiguration)` Removed invocation of function.

Comment: change .module('myApp') to  .module('myApp',[])

Comment: @Tushar Didn't work

Comment: @VinodLouis There are other injections being done in the myApp.module.js. I have removed them for brevity.

Comment: then use that reference here and add config its same appName with different config

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what are you doing! :|  (put constants in App, instead of base, and put routing in base instead of App, or reason of don't putting them together and so much other questions)
But maybe this will solve your problem.

myApp.module.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', [
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'myApp.common'
]);
```

myApp.config.js

```
'use strict';

angular
    .module('myApp')
    .constant('appConfig', applicationConfiguration)

function applicationConfiguration() {
    var config = {
        debug: true
    };

    switch (window.location.hostname) {
        case 'www.myapp.net':
            config.apiUrl = 'www.myapp.net/';
            config.publicSiteUrl = "www.myapp-public.net";
            break;
        case 'localhost':
            config.apiUrl = 'http://localhost:61057/';
            config.publicSiteUrl = "http://localhost:57563/";
            break;
    }

    return config;
}
```

use it:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.base', [
    'myApp',
    'ui.router',
])
    .config(['$stateProvider','appConfig', function configState($stateProvider, appConfig) {

        $stateProvider
            .state('public', {
                ...
            })
            .state('publicSite', {
                url: appConfig.publicSiteUrl,
                external: true
            });
    }])
    .run(function(){});
```

Comment: Myy references and injections were not right. There was a circular reference in code. This was just a simple representation of code. The real code was way more complex, but your sample did help me in revisit my code.